# How to add single value in a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql

my goal is to put the value of the 1 row in every row of the new column.
First value in this example is the number 10.
The New Table is showing my goal.

**Table**

```
Product ID     Name       Value  
1             ABC        10 
2             XYZ        22
3             LMM        8
```

**New Table**

```
Product ID     Name       Value  New Column
1             ABC        10         10
2             XYZ        22         10
3             LMM        8          10
```

I would fetch the value with the row_rumber function, but how i get that value in every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `first_value()`  [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
select product_id, name, value, 
       first_value(value) over (order by product_id) as new_column
from the_table
order by product_id;
```

Rows in a table have no implied sort order. So the "first row" can only be defined when an `order by` is present.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to pick the first one according to the product ID, you can do:

```
select *,
  ( select value 
    from (select *, row_number() over(order by product_id) as rn from t) x 
    where rn = 1
  ) as new_column
from t
```